# Validating Stylish Select with jquery.validation.js

Tags: jquery, validation

I've written some custom jQuery to validate [Stylish Select](https://github.com/scottdarby/Stylish-Select) inputs. Unfortunatley, I can't figure out how to prevent a form from submitting if those fields have errors. I'm using [jquery.validation.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). The problem I'm running in to is that when I try to prevent the form submitting it also prevents the jquery.validation.js script from running. I don't know if this makes any sense, but basically, is there a variable or something that jquery.validation.js uses that I can tie in to with my custom validation? Here's my custom script:

```
if ($("#field_1_87 select").attr("value") == "") {
  $("#field_1_87 .newListSelected").addClass("error");
  $("#field_1_87 .inputWrapper").prepend("<label class=\"error select\">This field is required.</label>");
}
// Error Counting
var errors = $(".error").length;
if (errors == 0) {
    $(form).submit();
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Please include a bit more source code, it's hard to tell whats wrong here without seeing the whole function.

Comment: It's a bit hard, the scripts I'm using are huge, so it's hard to know where to cut it off. I tried to localize it as much as possible. You can view the demo at http://www.olympicloans.com/users/apply-now/ (please don't tell me how horrible my JavaScript is, I realize it's a huge mess, but it works).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the link you provided in the comments:

You are using two undefined variables... you'll need to include the variable 'e' in the click function call:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) { ...
```

And you don't really need the $(form).submit() (form is undefined anyway):

```
if (errors > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This still causes the rest of the form validation to break.